# How does the Higgs mechanism work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, higgs, popular-science

I'm not a particle physicist, but I did manage to get through the Feynman lectures without getting too lost.
Is there a way to explain how the Higgs field works, in a way that people like me might have a hope of understanding?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6450/2451

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It will take me a few days to dig in and comprehend them.

Comment: See also [this popular description](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqNg819PiZY) by L. Susskind, or [this other](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVGknW4EaGA) by 't Hooft including pictures of the LHC and some nice diagrams.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Higgs mechanism is no different from superconductivity, except the condensate responsible for superconductivity is a relativistically invariant scalar field.

If you have a bosonic field, its particles can be in a Bose-Einstein condensate. When this condensate is charged, you call it a superconductor. A photon in a superconductor gets a mass, and this is the Higgs mechanism. For a relativistic boson described by a scalar field, you give the field a constant nonzero value to make a condensate. When the field has charge, this makes a superconducting condensate which gives the gauge boson a mass.

The whole effect is described in detail on the [Wikipedia page on the Higgs mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism), starting from a nonrelativistic superconductivity model of bosonic particles, and continuing analogously to relativistic condensates.

Comment: I hate to choose between these answers, but this one helps me more, given my extremely limited understanding.

Answer (score 3):

- simplest explanation without complex mathematical equation for a person don't have a wide knowledge about physics. Higgs Field, think of it as a field of people(audiences) waiting for a celebrity. Then think the celebrity as a particles and this celebrity(particle) walks toward the audience(higgs field). The more popular the celebrity is, the more people will mob him/her or let say the more interaction between the celebrity and the people, and less popular celebs less mob/interaction from the people. More interaction, more mass gains.
- everytime I discuss Higgs Boson/ Higgs Field/ Higgs Mechanisms, I'll start with this story so that the people I discuss it with already have a vision before I introduce to them heavy mathematics required to further explain the Higgs Boson/field/mechanisms.