# Explanation of the classical coupling of the Higgs Field to Electromagnetism

Tags: gauge-theory, field-theory, classical-electrodynamics, higgs

I'm interested in learning about the classical coupling of the Higgs Field to Electromagnetism. There are numerous sources explaining the Higgs mechanism quantum mechanically, i.e. [How does the Higgs mechanism work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/how-does-the-higgs-mechanism-work/17964#17964)

In addition to the question about classical coupling I'm also interested in how the Mexican hat describes charged particles?

Comment: Here is a set of video lectures: <http://sgovindarajan.wikidot.com/cftontheweb>. You might find lecture18 and lecture28 interesting. There isn't much of a difference between the classical and quantum case except that every classical field becomes an operator quantum mechanically, and hence can been interpreted as "quantized" into particles.

Comment: What is it about the sources you've already looked at that you don't understand? If you don't specify that, this just looks like a duplicate of the question you linked to and others like it.

Comment: I'm still unsure how the Mexican hat describes charged particles.