# What does the Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking with Higgs Mechanism imply effectively?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking, effective-field-theory

Suppose it is understood how the Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking work mathematically to give masses to Fermions through Yukawa Interactions and to Gauge Bosons via Higgs Mechanism.

In this case, ***my question***: how is a theory phenomenological description at energy scales $E \ll v$ different from the description at $E \gg v$ (where $v$ is the VEV responsible for SSB)?

To motivate the doubt above, suppose I have a breaking pattern $SU(3) \times SU(2) \to SU(2)' \times U(1)$ and I want to calculate the running of $g_{SU(3)}$. To do that, I should match both theories at a single scale. This matching is not analogous to what one does when integrating out heavy degrees of freedom suplying local interactions to a low energy effective model -- rather, it is about ensuring the lagrangians above and below that 'symmetry threshold' describe the same theory, numerically.

For example, if we have that the breaking pattern is such that $SU(2)' \subset SU(3)$, in that scale we must have $g_{SU(2)'}=g_{SU(3)}$, and if we have something like

$$
Y =\sum_\alpha p_\alpha T^\alpha,
$$

where $Y$ is the generator of $U(1)$ and $T^\alpha$ represent collectively  the 11 generators of $SU(3) \times SU(2)$, then the matching condition is

$$
\frac{1}{g_Y^2} = \sum_\alpha \frac{p_\alpha^2}{g_\alpha^2},
$$

where $g_\alpha$ is the coupling constant of the group corresponding to $T_\alpha$. This is what happens in the SM.

So, stating my question again: what is the use of this construction? At scales $E \gg v$, where one could say 'the symmetry is still unbroken', are the mass eigenstates of vector bosons still the degrees of freedom which propagate?

Comment: relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126497/does-the-higgs-boson-give-mass-to-all-other-particles and duplicate link

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69828/equivalence-theorem-of-the-s-matrix), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30664/the-meaning-of-goldstone-boson-equivalence-theorem).