# Has the speed of the higgs boson been measured yet?

Tags: higgs

Has the speed of the higgs boson been measured yet?
If not, what is it's speed predicted to be?

Comment: Particle with non-zero mass can take on any speed below the speed of light (given sufficient energy). Particles with zero mass are the only ones that have a fixed speed and they all have the same speed: $c$.

Comment: Can we say that applies to the higgs boson without testing the fact?

Comment: @Jitter: why do you think the Higgs boson would behave differently to any other massive particle?

Answer (score 1):

elementary particles do not have any particular speed. It could be could down untill almost zero motion, or it can be speeed up until becoming a black hole, who knows.

Comment: In theory then we could have a higgs condensate one day if we cool it down befor it decays;-)

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4511  for example. It just depends on the scale of "cool"

Comment: see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/how-does-the-higgs-mechanism-work