# Describing the Higgs mechanism to non-particle physicists

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, education, higgs

I'm sure I'm not the only person with this problem at the moment. I have been asked to give a public (not quite public, scientists, just not physicists) about 'this [Higgs boson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson) thing'. I am trying to think of a good analogy because even my own rather limited knowledge of the [Higgs mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) stretches to realising how bad the swimming through treacle metaphor is. I was wondering about refraction although I'm not sure how well understood that will be by a general audience? Superconductivity might be ok for physicsts but again probably rather specific for a more general audience.

Any other tips on how to pitch such a talk are appreciated but I'm aware I have to pose a specific question and describing the Higgs mechanism is the real conundrum.

Comment: I would urge you to not just dwell on the "mass giving" side, but rather its importance as part of the electroweak theory --- restoring unitarity and breaking symmetry. The mass aspect is really more of a side show, especially when hadron masses are almost entirely due to colour energy rather than Higgs interaction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an accepted analogy / conceptual aid for the Higgs field?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6450/is-there-an-accepted-analogy-conceptual-aid-for-the-higgs-field)

Comment: The linked question tells you the superconductor "analogy", which is ideal, because it isn't an analogy as much as the non-relativistic version of the same phenomenon.

Comment: Not analogies, but may be partially useful for conveying some ideas to a non specialist audience [this](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/11/21/why-do-we-expect-a-higgs-boson-part-i-electroweak-symmetry-breaking/) and [this](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2012/02/14/why-do-we-expect-a-higgs-boson-part-ii-unitarization-of-vector-boson-scattering/) articles by Flip Tanedo.