# Is this a reasonable intuition for the Higgs mechanism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, intuition

Though I've more or less come to terms with the math behind the Higgs mechanism, I'm trying to develop a rough intuition for it. Here's how I'm thinking: the Higgs field (like everything) likes to sit at a value which minimizes the potential. For the sombrero potential, at a minimizing value one can identify two directions: the 'angular' one, along which you still have minima of the potential, and the 'radial' one which changes the value of the potential. We expand the Higgs field in that basis, so to speak. The component along the angular direction is the one that corresponds to the massless Goldstone boson, and can be seen via gauge theory to not be physical. So as far as I understand the radial component is what's really the Higgs boson.

Since the field likes to sit at a minimum potential, if you nudge it somehow it'll have a tendency to go back to its resting value; this creates a sort of resistance, like mass is resistance to acceleration. Other fields, like the electron field, interact with the Higgs field; this means nudging the electron field will also nudge the Higgs field, which then provides a resistance, and that makes electrons also have mass.

While it's picturesque it's not very clear to me how the 'resistance to being nudged' gets identified with mass. The Newtonian analogy seems a bit of a stretch, and maybe if we could see it along the lines of $E^2 = p^2 + m^2$ it'd be more convincing.

Comment: Do you know QFT? It's the same identification that shows us that the mass is the coefficient of the quadratic term of a given field in the Lagrangian.

Comment: I know a little QFT, though I'm no expert. I'm comfortable with that identification in free theories, which can be explicitly solved to show that plane waves have on-shell momenta, but it seems more complicated to draw the connection in the case of interacting theories.

Comment: This explanation actually won an award - [The Higgs Field, explained - Don Lincoln](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joTKd5j3mzk)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17944/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6450/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Your got it ***badly*** wrong when it comes to the masses of the leptons, which have little to do with the Higgs mechanism. They arise out of the Yukawa couplings, and in particular the v.e.v. of SSB: *nothing to do with excitations* of the Higgs field! They would be the same if you made the Higgs infinitely massive (nonlinear σ model). No nudging there!